How to Run Functions in Parallel or in the Background in Django Without Using Celery/Redis?
I have a use case in my Django application where I want to run two functions in parallel or execute a process in the background. I don't want to use third-party tools like Celery, Redis, or similar services for this.
What I want to achieve:
Safely execute tasks in parallel or in the background.
Avoid slowing down the main request-response cycle.
I've heard that making internal API calls via HTTP (e.g., calling Django endpoints from within the same project) can be a faster alternative. Is this true and safe?
I don't want this to effected by the GIL in python

Have you tried Django Q or multiprocessing. Both can be used to safely execute tasks in parallel or in the background. Avoid slowing down the main request-response cycle.

you mean the process will continue running even after the API request response has closed ? WIll this work with gunicorn ?

yes it will work I have tried multiprocessing myself to run a function in background even when response cycle was closed.
